# Spring Data Elasticsearch to fetch Documents between two dates generates wrong query

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to fetch documents which are greater or lesser than  specified date.

I am using the below searchQuery for this purpose.

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()  
              .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date") 
                    .gt("2015-06-25T00:00:00")  
                    .lt("2015-06-25T00:00:00"));
```

The query generated from the above querybuilder is like this.

```
{  
  "bool" : {  
    "must" : [ {  
      "range" : {  
        "date" : {  
          "from" : "2015-06-25T00:00:00",  
          "to" : "2015-06-25T00:00:00",  
          "include_lower" : false,  
          "include_upper" : false  
        }  
      }  
    }  
    } ]  
  }
```

Even when i use functions **gt and lt of rangequery**  the query is generated as **from and to**.

What is the solution so that a query can be generated like this.

```
    {  
  "bool" : {  
    "must" : [ {  
      "range" : {  
        "date" : {  
          "gt" : "2015-06-25T00:00:00",  
          "lt" : "2015-06-25T00:00:00",  
          "include_lower" : false,  
          "include_upper" : false  
        }  
      }  
    }  
    } ]  
  }
```

This is the test class i have written.

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ElasticSearchConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ElasticSearchTest {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    @Test
    public void testAggregation(){

    QueryBuilder querybuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("receiptdate").gte("2015-06-25T00:00:00").lte ("2015-07-25T00:00:00")));

    final SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withQuery(qb)
                    .build();


  final List<Test> records = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Test.class);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this in Spring Data Elasticsearch would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your query would not return any results, since you're looking for dates strictly greater and strictly lower than the same date. You need to use `gte` and `lte` instead:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()  
          .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date") 
                .gte("2015-06-25T00:00:00")  
                .lte("2015-06-25T00:00:00"));
```

The [official parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) of the `range` query are `gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte`.

The `from`, `to`, `include_lower` and `include_upper` parameters are old deprecated parameters, which the [`RangeQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6acb8b31fca09ecea95e22c2ae6f18193b400055/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/RangeQueryBuilder.java#L283-L299) is still using but can (and will) be removed at anytime.

Just know that:

- `from` + `include_lower: false` is equivalent to `gt`
- `from` + `include_lower: true` is equivalent to `gte`
- `to` + `include_upper: false` is equivalent to `lt`
- `to` + `include_upper: true` is equivalent to `lte`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried this query but not getting records back from the server. This is the query **QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("receiptdate").gte("2015-06-25T00:00:00").lte("2015-07-25T00:00:00"))**

Comment: Can you show one document that you think should be returned?

Comment: This is a sample json {

    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "1015",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": "1015",
        " createdDate": "2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        " receiptnumber": "10150000187831 ",
        " paymentmode": "cash",
        " receiptdate": "2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        " installmentfrom": "2015-04-01",
        " installmentto": "2015-09-30",
        " reductionamount": null,
        " receiptcreator": ""
    }

}

Comment: Can you update your question with all the relevant Java code you're using to make this query?

Comment: I have updated the test class which i am using above.

Comment: Ok, how do you know there are no records since your test doesn't check the response you're getting? Also what happens if you execute the generated query directly via curl?

Comment: When i check through curl i get records.

Comment: My first question still stands.

Comment: I had replied with one  json document for that question.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. My question was "how do you know there are no records since your test doesn't check the response you're getting"?